# Render object in a select dropdown

Tags: reactjs

I'm a complete beginner to react.js and I really need some help, I'm trying to fetch some data from a mysql-database into a select-dropdown in react.js, but the data will be in an [object, Object] and does not load into the select.

My select-dropdown is not empty though, the "data" is just not visible in text. I.e, I got three items inside my food-object, and in my select-dropdown I get three BLANK items to choose between, and once I click on an "item" I get the error message saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

I've tried the solution from ([React selecting option with object as attribut value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564515/react-selecting-option-with-object-as-attribut-value)) but it does not work for (but it's the same problem though)

I've also tried to use JSON.stringify without any success. Advice is much appreciated!

```
class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        food: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetch('/test')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(food=> (
      this.setState({food}))
    );
}

 render() {
console.log(this.state);
return <div className="container">
    <div className="selection">
      <Select options={this.state.food} className="dropdown">
      {this.state.food.map((food, index) => (
          <option key={index} value={index}>
            {food.foodName}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <div> 

      <p> Listing data from mysql like this works {
        this.state.food.map(food => (
          <li key={food.foodName}>{food.foodName}</li>))}
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  }
}
 export default Test;
```

==========================

[What I can see in the console (response from the server)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHQPv.png)

Comment: Can you please show us some example JSON of what the response from the server looks like? Also, a couple issues. In your constructor, did you meant to do `this.handleFood = this.handleFood.bind(this)`? You have no function called `food`. Further, in your change function, you are setting the value of `food` to some undefined function, rather than to the changed value from the event...

Comment: Sorry, that  handleFood-function was not supposed  to be  there. I've deleted it. I've added a picture the response I get from the server. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON response from the server is:

```
{ food: [...] }
```

However, when you do:

```
.then(food => (
  this.setState({ food }))
);
```

Your setting your state to be:

```
{
  food: {
    food: [...],
  },
},
```

You need to access the `food` key in the response and set that as the value in state:

```
.then(response => {
  this.setState({ food: response.food });
});
```

Comment: So I changed my componentDidMount to:

componentDidMount() {
      fetch('/test')
        .then(response =>{
          this.setState({food: response.food} ); 
        });
    }

and it causes the react-app to crash due to "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

I gotta ask though, how come it work  to list the json-data in a <p> but not in <option>?