# Retrieving array of values from react select form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, reactstrap

So basically I'm attempting to create a form with a select dropdown box. I'm trying to send an array of values to the onChange function through the value property, but it just gives me a string instead. How can I pass the values back and access them in an array style?

The reactjs site shows that this is possible under the select Tag, but not how to access the values...

> https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag

```
    <Input type="select" name="university" id="university" onChange={this.onSelect}>

    {this.props.universities.universities.map(({ idUniversity, name}) => (
       <option key ={idUniversity} value = {[idUniversity , name]}>
         {name}
       </option>
    ))}

    </Input>
```

```
    onSelect = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value[0] + " " + e.target.value[1] );
        this.setState({
            university_id: e.target.value[0],
            university_name: e.target.value[1]
        });
    }
```

When I run this, e.target.value[0] gives me the first character of the entire string given by {[idUniversity , name]}.

So for example, the array should be [2, University of Central Florida], but e.target.value[0] will return just [

Comment: May this be because you are forgetting to add the `multiple` attribute to the `<select>` element?

Comment: @OriolGrau If I add that, it changes the dropdown selector into a multiple select box. And unfortunately, it still doesn't change the value attribute into an array, so same problem.

Comment: is `let [id, name] = e.target.value.split(',')` good enough for you? I'm trying to see if there is another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564515/react-selecting-option-with-object-as-attribut-value) has some possible ways of going about it using the `index` to select the items from your initial data, however in your case it might just be easiest to `split` the value back into array form:

```
onSelect = (e) => {
    const [university_id, university_name] = e.target.value.split(',');

    this.setState({
        university_id,
        university_name,
    });
}
```