# How Can I create a Handle an input object with React hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have problem in my input object how can I change the onChage function this is my input code

```
<Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridResultat">
                                                            <Form.Label>Result</Form.Label>
                                                            <Form.Control required as="select"
                                                                type="text"
                                                                id="conduexam.id"
                                                                name="conduexam.id"
                                                                value={currentStates. conduexam?.nom}
                                                                className={"bg-white text-dark"}
                                                                onChange={handleInputChange}>

                                                                <option value="">Choisir un Resultat </option>
                                                                {result.map((value) => (
                                                                    <option value={value.id} key={value.id}>
                                                                        {value.nom}
                                                                    </option>
                                                                ))}

                                                            </Form.Control>

                                                        </Form.Group>
```

The function “onChange” how can I change it?

```
const handleInputChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setCurrentStates({ ...currentStates, [name]: value });
    };
```

Comment: "how can I change it?" ... change it *how*?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Lili  How does the `result` array look like ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const [currentStates, setCurrentStates]= useState({
//your initial code here
})

const handleInputChange = event => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
        setCurrentStates({ ...currentStates, [name]: event.target.value});
   };
```

Comment: Can’t workit make me a error with the [name]

Comment: You need to check your `value` inside the form